# Python "if X == Y and Z" syntax

Tags: python, if-statement

Does this:

```
if key == "name" and item:
```

mean the same as this:

```
if key == "name" and if key == "item":
```

If so, I'm totally confused about [example 5.14 in Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/special_class_methods.html). How can key be equal to both "name" and item? On the other hand, does "and item" simply ask whether or not item exists as a variable?

Comment: If you want a good primer on this check out boolean or conditional logic.

Comment: When you tried it, what did you observe?  Please post the results of your evaluations.  You can run this in interactive Python and post the results.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`if key == "name" and item:` means `if (key == "name") and (item evaluates to True)`.

Keep in mind that `(item evaluates to True)` is possible in several ways. For example `if (key == "name") and []` will evaluate to `False`.

Comment: @paracaudex: No!! After `$b = 0;`, `isset($b)` evaluates to true, but `$b` is false. And `isset(true)` is nonsense, while `while True` is *the* way to write an infinite loop.

Comment: @paracaudex: A better equivalent to isset($b) in Python would be ("b" in locals() or "b" in globals()).  But that would be somewhat strange and unusual Python; normally the set of variables in scope when particular code runs should be statically predictable.

Answer (score 13):

Manoj explained it well. Here goes some complementary notes.

The pseudocode

```
if key == "name" or if key == "item":
```

should be this way:

```
if key == "name" or key == "item":
```

An interesting idiom to do it is:

```
if key in ("name", "item"):
```

but it is more useful for really large conditions where you just want to know if some value is equal to any other value from a list.

Answer (score 4):

No, you have to repeat the expression. It evaluates as 2 separate conditions, and checks if both are true -

1. `x == y`
2. `z`

Check the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) for a list of what is considered False in Python

(However, interesting to note that, as opposed to other languages, the following:

```
if 3 < x < 6
```

is equivalent to

```
if x > 3 and x < 6
```

)

Answer (score 4):

If, hypothetically, you did want

```
if key == "name" and if key == item:
```

you could do this

```
if key == "name" == item:
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained how the expression you're asking about is evaluated. An important thing to know is that if the first operand of the "and" operator evaluates to false, the second one is never evaluated, because the result of "and" is always false if one operand is false, and if you know the first operand is false, then the whole "and" is false and you don't have to evaluate the second. This is called "short-circuiting" and applies to "or" as well as "and" (except that "or" is always true when either operand is true, so the second operand is evaluated only when the first is false).

The other thing you need to know is that the result of the whole "and" operation is the value of the last operand evaluated. Since things other than the literal constants True and False are considered logically true or false, this fact (combined with short-circuiting) can be used as a substitute for "if" statements in some situations, and you will occasionally see it used that way.

For example, "x or y" evaluates to x if x is true, but to y if x is false. Sometimes this is used to provide defaults for missing values:

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name: ") or "dude"
print "Hello, %s!" % name
```

If you don't enter anything at the prompt, just hit Enter, the return value of raw_input is the empty string, "", which is considered false. Since the left branch of the "or" is false, it doesn't short-circuit, and the right branch is evaluated, so the result of the "or" is "dude."  If you do enter a value at the prompt, the right branch never gets evaluated, due to short-circuiting, and so the value of the "or" is whatever you entered.

A lot of people consider abusing Boolean operators this way to be poor style now that Python has "x if y else z," but this particular use strikes me as readable enough.  (But this is about the only one!) "The value is this, or that if it's empty."  Compare it to the following:

```
name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
name = name if name else "dude"
print "Hello, %s!" % name
```

Answer (score 1):

*@Manoj* is correct in describing the behavior and specifies the correct equivalent statement. however, i would wish to discuss short circuiting ie the mechanics of what is evaluating.

`x and y`  is short hand for

```
if x:
  return y
else:
  x
```

evaluation goes:

```
if key == "name" and item:
```

`key == "name" and item` will evaluate first.

if *`key != "name"`* then we will return *`False`* and the condition is evaluated upon this value and no action occurs.

however if *`key == "name"`* we will return *`item`*. *`item`* now becomes the condition of the if loop

```
if item:
 # action :: do something
```

and action specified underneath the if block will then follow if *`item`* also exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the code for example 5.14:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, item):         
    if key == "name" and item:            
        self.__parse(item)                
    FileInfo.__setitem__(self, key, item)
```

`item` is a variable, similar to how key is.

It can be used in the `if` statement if it evaluates into either `true` or `false`.

eg.

```
happy = True
name = "Peter"
if name == "Peter" and happy:
    print name + " is happy!"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Victor Neo: Also you do not need separate boolean:

```
for happy in (False, "Peter", '', "Susan" , []):
    print(happy + ' is happy.' if happy else 'Everybody is bored.')
```

If statement is preferred over using `or` and `and` with non-booleans, which emulated the effect before `value if condition else value` became available in Python.