# Multiple Python if-statments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't usually develop in Python but I have a few IDE's and Code Editors that I often use and switch between. To make it more convenient for myself, I thought I'd make a quick Python program that launches my IDE's/Editor's based on an input. The issue is, every time I run the program, the first if-statment always validates as true and runs that action.

Here is my code:

```
import os

#NOTE: I have trimmed the root directories here to save space. Just removed the subfolder names, but the programs are the same. 

notepadPlusPlusLaunch = "C:\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe"
bracketsLaunch = "C:Brackets\\Brackets.exe"
aptanaLaunch = "C:Aptana Studio\\AptanaStudio3.exe"
devCppLaunch = "C:Dev-Cpp\\devcpp.exe"
githubLaunch = "C:GitHub,  Inc\\GitHub.appref-ms"
androidLaunch = "C:android-studio\\bin\\studio64.exe"
ijLaunch = "C:bin\\idea.exe"
pycharmLaunch = "C:JetBrains\\PyCharm  4.0.5\\bin\\pycharm.exe"
sublimeLaunch = "C:Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe"

def launcherFunction(command):
    os.startfile(command)

launchCommand = input("")

if launchCommand == "notepad" or "npp" or "n++" or "n":
    launcherFunction(notepadPlusPlusLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "brackets" or "b":
    launcherFunction(bracketsLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "aptana" or "as" or "webide":
    launcherFunction(aptanaLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "dcpp"or "c++":
    launcherFunction(devCppLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "gh" or "github" or "git" or "g":
    launcherFunction(githubLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "android" or "a" or "as":
    launcherFunction(androidLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "java" or "ij" or "idea" or "j":
    launcherFunction(ijLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "python" or "pc" or "p":
    launcherFunction(pycharmLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "code" or "sublime" or "html" or " " or "s" or "php" or "css" or "js" or "jquery":
    launcherFunction(sublimeLaunch)

elif launchCommand == "help":
        print(notepadPlusPlusLaunch, "\n", bracketsLaunch, "\n", aptanaLaunch, "\n", devCppLaunch, "\n",githubLaunch, "\n", androidLaunch, "\n", ijLaunch, "\n",     pycharmLaunch, "\n", sublimeLaunch, "\n", musicLaunch,"\n")

else: 
    print("Invalid Entry")
```

I'm not getting any errors but everytime I run this, the first if-statment always validates as true. So from this code, it keeps launching Notepad++. Can anyone tell what what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: `if launchCommand == "notepad" or "npp" or "n++" or "n"` is wrong

Comment: May be helpful: [Python newbie: “if X == Y and Z” syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629586/python-newbie-if-x-y-and-z-syntax)

Comment: This might help you understand, type this into your interpreter: `if 'hello': print('yes')`

Comment: Can I just comment that you try to use "as" variable twice with aptanaLaunch and androidLaunch.

Comment: @jester112358  Didn't notice that, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if launchCommand == "notepad" or launchCommand == "npp" or launchCommand == "n++" or launchCommand == "n":
```

or even better

```
if launchCommand in ("notepad", "npp", "n++", "n"):
```

Your original if statement will always evaluates to `True` because it is equivalent to:

```
if (launchCommand == "notepad") or ("npp") or ("n++") or ("n"):
```

and non-empty strings are casted to `True` in a logical operation.

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations
- https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: It would be great if you add an explanation why `launchCommand == "notepad" or launchCommand == "npp" or launchCommand == "n++" or launchCommand == "n"` always evaluates into `True`